# Deathwatch - Horde Rules

Tags: warhammer-40k, deathwatch

The horde rules in Deathwatch appear to be how the game intends to represent large, tightly clustered mobs of enemies.

How do I represent hordes on the table?  I use 1m squares.  Do I move it as a solid mass, or a fluid mass?  (Example: Can it or can it not flow through a narrow alley?)

The size is determined by how high the magnitude is, which I believe the book details how much total space that takes up in the game rules section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon the Free RPG day demo, I'd do one of several things:

1. simply use enough models in base-to-base contact for the magnitude (if I have them)
2. use a large card base with two models double stick taped to it, and space to mark off casualties.
3. use a larger scale square (say 5m, and each 10 men are 1 square).
4. use a whiteboard, and simply draw a suitably sized base.

When I demoed it for my FLGS, I used option 4.

If I'd had the models accessible, I'd have used my old Space Marine models.

As far as moving it as a fluid mass vs rigid mass, fluid, of course.